# Authentication with NestJS and GRPC server

Tags: node.js, grpc, nestjs

I'm trying to authenticate my users in NestJS with microservice GRPC, but I can't send a `Set-Cookie` header to send the JWT token.

```
@GrpcMethod('Auth', 'SignIn')
async signIn(data: my.api.auth.SignInRequest): Promise<any> {
    try {
        const response = await this.authService.signIn(data.email, data.password);
        const metadata = new grpc.Metadata();
        metadata.set(
            'Set-Cookie',
            `token=${response.jwt}; Expires=${response.expiresIn}; HttpOnly`,
        );

        return metadata;
    } catch (error) {
        throw new RpcException({
            code: grpc.status.NOT_FOUND,
            message: 'User not found',
        });
    }
}
```

I don't want to send the JWT in my response and set the cookie in frontend side because it's a bad practice to not set this kind of cookie without `HttpOnly`. But I don't know how to return to my frontend the `Set-Cookie` header.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

From what I see, is trying to create some metadata on the server, where I created them, I've always been in the GRPC client and I pass it as a second paramenter to the GRPC server call, I hope this helps